# Pattern recognition and prediction in C# or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, random, pattern-recognition

I started working on a small project - at least I thought so.

The idea is simple - I have a list of boolean values, which were randomly generated (provably fair but not completely random engine). Due to the engine's non-randomness, there are emerging patterns in the boolean outcome.

What I wish to do is quite simple in theory: recognize the pattern early on, and predict the next one based on all the previous data sets. I do realize that an actual implementation will be extremely frustrating to work with.

Could anyone give me an idea where to start with this?

Comment: Which patterns do you wish to recognize?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests

Comment: @fonix232 : Question is not clear enough it would be good if you add some examples

Comment: @Asad Simple patterns like a repeating true,false,true,false or true,true,false,false, or a line of one value with one discrepancy of the other value (say 15 true values in a line, with 11 being a false - here I do not wish to predict the false value, but see that it is a line of true's and use that information).

Basically I wish to increase the probability of guessing the upcoming result in most of the cases - to increase the overall chance of having more and more results guessed correctly.

MithunGanatra I hope this explanation is precise enough!

Comment: No, I don't think it is precise enough, neither for me nor for coding it.